# Can Not Delete Control in VS2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

At the top of the Properties Window in VS2010, I can see a list of all of the controls on my form.  In that last, I see "PictureBox1," even though I don't see a corresponding PictureBox in the Form window.

I can change the location and size of the PictureBox, and set its image to a picture that should be noticeable.  I still see nothing on the GUI form.  If I can't find something to click on the GUI form, however, I don't know how to get rid of this superfluous PictureBox.

Is there some backdoor method that I can use to get rid of this PictureBox?  It seems if the Properties Window lists it, it should offer some method to delete it.

Comment: Try going into the designer file and removing it there.

Comment: Could you please show us the form code behind? You could manage all your components in the designer file.

Comment: Tim, this was successful.  I used Eclipse to find every instance of PictureBox1 in the project source.  When I reopened it in VS2010, the PictureBox1 control no longer showed up in the Properties window.

Answer (score 2):

A simple explanation is that it is covered by something else.  Use View + (Other Windows) + Document Outline to see it.  You can drag+drop it back on top.  Or just right-click + Delete and its gone.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about this view!  The PictureBox1 control, however, didn't show up in the view.  Overall, however, the view looks very useful.